# How to change input field size with selenium

Tags: web-applications, selenium, selenium-ide, fuzzing

I am testing a web application with `selenium` and I am having a little problem with one specific input field. Is there any way to change the size of a input field with `selenium`?

Example: The max length of a input field is 8 and I want to change it to 20.

Answer (score 1):

unlikely you will be able to change input field size as this parameter is fixed (hardcoded). The only thing you can do with selenium is to check how the application accepts e.g. 8 symbol input and 20 symbol input and verify e.g whether validator appears or not.

```
//8 symbols
String check1="blablabl";
//20 symbols
String check2="blablablablablablabl";
driver.findElement(By.id("input1")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("input1")).sendKeys(check2); 
//verify that appropriate error appeared
Assert.assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("xpath of validator message")));

driver.findElement(By.id("input1")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("input1")).sendKeys(check1);
```

Something like that.
Hope this be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Curious why u wanna change from max8 to max20? This suppose a Unit Testing that will fail if the max8 fields manage to accept till max20?

Got 1 trick can help u check on this.. use FireBug .. change the HTML allow max8 to max20.. and manually key in the max20 items in..

if Your application does not have server site checking, this trick shall be able to save the 20 character in provided that your DB allow this max20 to be store.. (If this was success, means your application having some security loop hole already) good luck..  :D